# To prevent sex were men bound in bags or locked in beds?

Tags: cultural-history, marriage, family, sex, childbirth

I remember in the past, before marriage, a woman’s family would bind her man when he stayed with her in a sleeping bag or bed.

Essentially it would lock him into this bag/bed thing so he couldn’t leave during the night and come over to her room or something along the lines of that.

I saw it in a movie: The Patriot (2000), I wanted some sort of confirmation of the historical practice if I could get it.

Comment: Are you possibly thinking of [bundling](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/the-awkward-17thcentury-dating-practice-that-saw-teens-get-bundled-into-bags) by any chance?

Comment: That’s exactly what it was!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @njuffa you might want to move that to an answer, so can accept.  Questions with answers are less likely to be closed.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace A link does not an answer make and I don't think I am qualified to even summarize the article at Atlas Obscura, having merely skimmed it some months ago.

Comment: @Jared says you've answered the question.  I would never have inferred that answer from that question, so I think you deserve the credit.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to increase its search hits.

Answer (score 3):

Bundling was a technique of separating two people of the opposite sex by textile devices to allow intimate contact without the possibility of intercourse during courtship.
It is thought to have originated in the British Isles in the 17th century. Further information can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_(tradition)) and [Atlas Oscura](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/the-awkward-17thcentury-dating-practice-that-saw-teens-get-bundled-into-bags).

Comment: As described in the linked article, this practice had less to do with chastity and more with poverty: `some people made or bought beds with an easily inserted bundling board so they could rent out half a bed to travelers with ease` - and: `The origins of bundling may have come, as Stiles suggested, from a simple lack of fuel and cash in the cold winter months. `